# React-Router/Redux browser back button functionality

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, browser-history, html5-history

I'm building a 'Hacker News' clone, [***Live Example***](https://ryanaltobello.com/hacker-news/news.html)  using React/Redux and can't get this final piece of functionality to work. I have my entire `App.js` wrapped in `BrowserRouter`, and I have `withRouter` imported into my components using `window.history`. I'm pushing my state into `` window.history.pushState(getState(), null, `/${getState().searchResponse.params}`) `` in my API call action creator. `console.log(window.history.state)` shows my entire application state in the console, so it's pushing in just fine. I guess. In my main component that renders the posts, I have

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      window.history.go(event.state);
    };
  }
....I also tried window.history.back() and that didn't work
```

what happens when I press the back button is, the URL bar updates with the correct previous URL, but after a second, the page reloads to the main index URL(homepage). Anyone know how to fix this? I can't find any real documentation(or any other questions that are general and not specific to the OP's particular problem) that makes any sense for React/Redux and where to put the `onpopstate` or what to do insde of the `onpopstate` to get this to work correctly.

***EDIT: Added more code below***

#### Action Creator:

```
export const searchQuery = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {

 (...)

  if (noquery && sort === "date") {
    // DATE WITH NO QUERY
    const response = await algoliaSearch.get(
      `/search_by_date?tags=story&numericFilters=created_at_i>${filter}&page=${page}`
    );
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_POSTS", payload: response.data });
  } 

(...)

  window.history.pushState(
    getState(),
    null,
    `/${getState().searchResponse.params}`
  );
  console.log(window.history.state);
};
```

^^^ This logs all of my Redux state correctly to the console through `window.history.state` so I assume I'm implementing `window.history.pushState()` correctly.

#### PostList Component:

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.onpopstate = () => {
      window.history.back();
    };
  }

(...)

}
```

I tried changing `window.history.back()` to `this.props.history.goBack()` and didn't work. Does my code make sense? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the History API?

Answer (score 0):

withRouter HOC gives you history as a prop inside your component, so you don't use the one provided by the window.

You should be able to access the window.history even without using withRouter.

so it should be something like:

```
const { history } = this.props;
history.push() or history.goBack()
```

Comment: I added some code to help visualize what I have and how it's setup